# Issues with Material UI and Next.js

Tags: material-ui, next.js

When ever I refresh the page the styling material UI select component looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the styling is not applied correctly. I'm on next 9.5.1 and material ui 4.11.0. The strange is that if this issue only occures when i hard refresh the page. Whenever the dev server refreshes the styling works as intended.

Heres the code for the selector:

```
       <FormControl className="form-control">
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select value={price} variant="outlined" onChange={handleChange}>
          {PRICE.map(item => (
            <MenuItem value={item}>{'test'}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the customized _document.js file :/